# Glimpse + MVC5 + Sitecore 7.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore, glimpse, sitecore7.2

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 website and I have installed Glimpse.MVC5 using nuget. The website is running the latest version of the Sitecore CMS (7.2 rev. 140314). I haven't changed the Glimpse configuration at all apart from adding logging.

When I go to the homepage of the website (after enabling Glimpse) I can't see the HUD. The following is the last line in the Glimpse log:

> 2014-04-24 15:19:01.6043 | DEBUG | Apparently GlimpseRuntime has not
>   yet initialized this request. This might happen in case you're doing
>   something specific like mentioned in this issue:
>   https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/703 . Either way, Glimpse
>   will be disabled to prevent any further non-deterministic behavior
>   during this request.

I've had a look at the link but I can't see that it applies to my situation. There are no NullReferenceException's in the log.

I have tested Glimpse.MVC5 with a vanilla ASP.NET MVC5 website on my machine and that worked fine so I'm tempted to assume that it's something to do with Sitecore.

Any ideas what could be wrong or ideas on how to identify the issue?

Comment: The reason you are not seeing those `NullReferenceException`s is due to the fact that they were solved and replaced with a message like the one you mentioned above.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [Glimpse for Sitecore](http://kevinobee.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/glimpse-for-sitecore/) module

Comment: @jammykam Correct me if I'm wrong but the Glimpse for Sitecore module is just a plugin that adds more information (tabs) to the base Glimse HUD. If the main HUB doesn't display I don't expect the Sitecore module to work either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution mentioned in [this](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/336) post on the Glimpse issue tracker solved the problem.

> Sitecore does it's own HttpModule stuff which seems to
>   cause issues.
>
> In order to fix this, you need to move the Glimpse HttpModule
>   definition before the Sitecore modules in the Web.config.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are still not seeing the HUD is explained by that log message as well.

Somehow during the execution of the request, a *new* `HttpContext` is created or used which means you'll loose the request initialization that Glimpse did at `BeginRequest`. As part of that initialization, items are being stored in the `HttpContext.Items` collection for which Glimpse will look during request monitoring.

The message you see in the log is an example of when Glimpse wants to know what the current `RuntimePolicy` is, so that it knows whether or not it should continue to monitor that request. The current `RuntimePolicy` is set by Glimpse during the `BeginRequest` phase of that request and the log now indicates it cannot find it, after which Glimpse decides to be concervative and stop monitoring that request instead of ending in a `NullReferenceException`

Now the cases where we've seen that (check the linked issues inside the issue you mentioned) is when another `HttpContext` is being created and used to process that request **after** that Glimpse did is initialization.

So the only advice I can give here, is to check whether the creation of another `HttpContext` is actually the case for you? You might find some ideas in those linked issues.

In case you find something specific that is not related to the issue mentioned above, then I would suggest you create a new issue on [our issue tracker](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues) as it is a more appropriate place to discuss potential bugs or missing features